# Is there any reason why PHP files require write permissions?

Tags: linux, php, permissions

Is there any reason why PHP files would require write access? (Excluding directories that need to be writable)

I'm installing Magento via composer. [They recommend](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html#set-file-permissions) the following permissions:

```
cd /var/www/html/<magento install directory>
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Doing this makes the files writable. This is problematic. I also use the [snuffleupagus](https://snuffleupagus.readthedocs.io/) PHP module to add a level of security. But, this also causes an issue when installing Magento because I get the error:

```
2019/12/02 03:48:57 [error] 6782#6782: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  [snuffleupagus][0.0.0.0][readonly_exec] Attempted execution of a writable file (/var/www/shop/app/etc/vendor_path.php). in /var/www/shop/app/autoload.php on line 25" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: ucp.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:
```

I'm wondering whether to make most of these files readable/executable as there is no reason for them to be writable on the server. Is there any reason why one shouldn't do this?

Comment: *"Is there any reason why PHP files require write permissions?"* - The documentation you refer to clearly says why it needs the files to be writable: *"This is necessary __so that the Setup Wizard and command line can write files__ to the Magento file system."*. This is actually the second sentence in the paragraph you link to, before it even shows the command to execute.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering whether to make most of these files readable/executable

**PHP files do not need to be executable**. That could be worse than having the write permission.

Furthermore, in the specific directories mentioned (e.g., var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc) write permissions are probably required (at least for some file types). I have not tested it in depth, but generally it will break my Magento site if I don't give the permissions recommended (or a variation of them as I will mention next).

Recently I have been experimenting with an alternative permission scheme that I believe improves security. I asked a question about it here:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297324/linux-file-permissions-on-webroot-for-magento-2-when-755-and-644-are-not-good-en

The question comes from reading "You can have your cake and eat it too" at https://serverfault.com/a/357109. When I asked the question, I had not tried that scheme with Magento. I have tried it now and it works very well.

The other thing to be sure you have done is [modify docroot to improve security](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html). After doing this you should not have any executable files in the DocumentRoot of your Magento site. You can check from the command line like this:

```
find pub/ -type f -executable
```